# How can I get the JavaScript documents in use?

Tags: javascript

How can I get from my web browser the external javaScript documents used on the current website. the aplication is not using all the .js, I tried to look up with the console, but the information is confusing. is there any way that i can get the .js documents running in a current html compile by the web browser

Comment: Did you run the firebug profiler then check what files were called?

Comment: thanks @SmokeyPHP I just review the tool, it seems to be use full I am goint to try it. I don't know much about this tools

Comment: most scripts typically leave behind a <script> tag, but it can be removed, so the debugger is the only final say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aside from disabling them one by one, and/or manually checking yourself using Chrome's Developer Tools or Firefox's Firebug... there is no solution that can know every document that could potentially be used in your page.

When a button is clicked, you could dynamically bring in some content that your browser knew nothing about, which suddenly uses one of the linked JS files.  Therefore no solution can tell you what you are asking for.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174988/detect-linked-unused-files-and-unused-javascript

Comment: @BarbaraLaird no, that solution will tell you code that is unreachable.  the OP could have a lot of "reachable" code that is simply never invoked.